# Can I Compare the day name with the date Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am working on news function. News model contains publishing date....
Is there a way to filter my record from db on the base of Publishing Date's day name such as in controller action:

```
var data1 = db.News.Where(x => x.PublishingDate >= DateTime.Now
    && x.PublishingDate.Day == (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday);
ViewBag.SundayNews = data1;
```

Or if there is another way around or any reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution: http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.ru/2011/12/getting-dayofweek-in-linq-to-entities.html

```
var firstSunday = new DateTime(1753, 1, 7); 
var filtered = from e in dbContext.Entities
               where EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, e.SomeDate) % 7 == (int)DayOfWeek.Monday 
               select e;
```

`firstSunday` stores the minimal value for MS SQL DATETIME type.